# Image won't load in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

Thanks in advance for the help. I'm making a web app that saves an image file as part of the 'create' and 'edit' actions on the CauseController for that model. However, despite successfully being able to create a new Folder in the Content directory and save an image for each instance created, I can't get the photo to appear in the built view.

This is the model class (it's for a project similar to change.org):

```
public class Cause
{   

    [Key]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CauseTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public string CatagoryTitle { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CatagoryTitle")]
    public Catagory Catagory { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }
}
```

This is the [Post] Create action method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CauseTitle,Description,Author,DatePosted,CatagoryTitle")] Cause cause, HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (UploadImage != null)
            {
                if (UploadImage.ContentType == "image/jpg" || UploadImage.ContentType == "image/png" || UploadImage.ContentType == "image/bmp" || UploadImage.ContentType == "image/gif" || UploadImage.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
                {
                    string causeTitle = cause.CauseTitle;
                    string subPath = "~/Content/" + causeTitle; // your code goes here
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));

                    UploadImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(subPath) + "/" + UploadImage.FileName);
                    cause.ImageURL = subPath + causeTitle + UploadImage.FileName;
                }
                else
                    return View();
            }
            else
                return View();
            db.Causes.Add(cause);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

            ViewBag.CatagoryTitle = new SelectList(db.Catagories, "CatagoryTitle", "CatagoryDescription", cause.CatagoryTitle);
            return View(cause);
        }
```

And this is the part of the view:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(@item.ImageURL) background-size: 100%" >
    <img src="urlPath" alt="urlPath" />
    <h1>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CauseTitle)</h1>
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Description)</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Sign Cause</a></p>
</div>
```

The resulting Element shows as  in Chrome Developer for this attempt.

I have also tried this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CauseTitle)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Catagory.CatagoryTitle)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatePosted)
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="@item.ImageURL" alt="Alternate Text" />
        </td>
```

The Element shows  in Chrome Developer for this example. In this case, this is the correct file path.

I've looked in the database at the Causes table and the values the ImageUrl columns follow this pattern (as expected): ~/Content/[Cause Title]/[Image Title].jpg.

I've looked at all the other answers to similar questions and couldn't find a solution that worked for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean the image won’t show? When the view loads, what do you see in the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the browser, I see the generic image thumbnail followed by "urlPath". In visual studio, when I explicitly state the path i.e. write "~/Content/[Cause Title]/[Image Title].jpg." I can see the img on screen when I hover over it. When I use the @item.ImageUrl (which is the same path in string form) I get "No Image Available" when I hover over it, with Couldn't locate file. But I've checked that the string in the database table is the same as what's in the scr="" on the img tag when I've successfully displayed it. Cheers

Comment: You need to inspect the html of the rendered page to see how the output of the image url has been built, there must be something wrong there.

Comment: Check the actual _rendered_ values - e.g. quoted url for `background-image`, etc. View Source and Dev Tools in browser (particularly network tab and look for `404`s)

Comment: A tilde (~) is not valid in a client-side path

Comment: Thanks for that I will check now. I've added html tag from the Inspect Element display from the Chrome Developer to the original question. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem's solved. I had to save the img (Server side) with the tilde, but save the url string without the tilde, so that it would load (client side), and that's worked fine. Thanks again for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your final td to use @Url.Content as shown below. This always gives a relative path.

```
<td>
       <img src="@Url.Content(item.ImageURL)" alt="Alternate Text" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img alt="VectorI130" src="~/Img/public/playground_assets/vector4244-23wc.svg"
class="side-navbar-vector" />
```

use this ~ to load images in version 4 or Higher